# How to handle click in winforms button that also has DragnDrop?

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a little panel that supports DragnDrop on MouseDown.  But I also have a MouseClick event I want to handle if the user does not drag outside the box.  How to do that?  I tried recording the start position on MouseDown, then measuring in MouseMove and calling DoDragDrop once it exceeded 10 pixels.  But I get the little circle with a slash through it as soon as I click in the box.  Is DoDragDrop only supported on MouseDown?  I saw another post similar to this where it is suggested to measure the distance, but they don't explain how to enable MouseClick instead of the DoDragDrop...

```
    private void oldPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        m_nStartDragPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    private void oldPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Math.Abs(e.X - m_nStartDragPoint.X) > 10 ||
            System.Math.Abs(e.Y - m_nStartDragPoint.Y) > 10)
        {
            oldPanel.DoDragDrop(oldPanel, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    private void oldPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do some stuff - not called currently
    }
```

Comment: You quit too soon, you already know what to do.  Yes, MouseDown and MouseMove required, make it so.  You are not going to see anything else but the stop-sign until you move the mouse over a control that has AllowDrop = true.

Comment: Hm - okay thanks, but I guess my real question is how to cancel the DragNDrop if they don't move enough, so that the Click event is called? I overedited my code in the question, I will update.

Comment: I found a solution -- I didn't realize that MouseMove was being called even when hovering the mouse.  So I have to keep track of mouseDown and only call dragndrop when the mouse is both down and moving.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this, or *a* solution, was to keep track of mouseDown as well as position.  MouseMove is called even when hovering -- the mouse doesn't actually have to be pressed.  So it was always calling DoDragDrop.